# page created with css not becoming responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First of all, sorry if the question was too dumb...

I started learning CSS two weeks before and as for practice I have started a side project to apply what I learn... As a result of my learning, I have done the below website.. Its just an homepage... the only issue is.. If i resize the browser to check the responsiveness, it cuts the part on the right and bottom of the welcome content at the bottom...

I have tried and applied everything i found on internet, but unable to crack it.. Kindly help on this.. oh, and also rather than just telling the error, it would be really nice if you could say how it works so that I could learn it and use it on future... Thanks..

since it is large, the code is in the below link.. PLease help...

http://jsbin.com/fimot/3/edit

Comment: I cannot tell what is supposed to go where based on your example.  Can you explain where you would like the elements to reside and appear?  Should the paragraph be in the banner?  Right now it is outside of it.

Comment: actually the text and content should be where it is wrt to the page size.. If I resize the browser, the text automatically hides inside the banner rather than overflowing or resizing...

Answer (score 0):

`.box.login` is using percentage sizes, which are relative to the container size, which is relative to the viewport size. So, in reality, your layout *is responsive* - just more responsive than you're wanting it to be.

My recommendation would be to add a `min-width` CSS property in e.g. ems (so that it's not relative to the container's width), in order to keep it from getting below a size that would make it ugly/unusable.

Answer (score -1):

Your `.box.login` has variable values, which are dependent on the screen size. You should use fix values here (e.g. `px`) to get it working on resize. Then it won't be resized, which should be preferred in this case.